# Calling indexer from within the same (generic) class

Tags: c#, generics, indexer

```
public class MyClass<T>
{
        public T this[int index]
        {
            get
            {
                ...
            }
            set
            {
                ...
            }
        }

        public void MyMethod<T>()
        {   
             int middleIndex = ...;              
             T value = this[middleIndex ];     
             ...             
        }           
}
```

The code won't compile because of the statement in MyMethod(). Is there another way of calling the indexer ?

Edit: Modified MyMethod()

Edit2: Compilation error

```
Error    6    Cannot implicitly convert type 'T [C:\MyClass.cs]' to 'T [C:\MyClass.cs]'
```

Thanks.

Comment: Where is `index` defined in `MyMethod`?

Comment: If I replace MyMethod with "public void MyMethod(int index)" the example compiles perfectly fine.

Comment: The code you posted looks fine.  Can you post more of `MyMethod`?

Comment: And is this unwillingness to compile expressed in some kind of compile time error, computer crashing, apples falling from the sky that you would like to share or maybe you expect us reading your mind?

Comment: Adding the the compiler error would help in diagnosing why this doesn't work for you.

Comment: Are you sure you have only that T in your class ? Isn't, by any chance,T another class or `MyMethod` generic as well ?(like `MyMethod<T>`)

Comment: @digEmAll I had a T in MyMethod(). It worked when I removed it. Thanks !

Answer (score 4):

Works fine for me:

```
public class MyClass<T>
{
    public T this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            return default(T);
        }
        set
        {
        }
    }

    public void MyMethod(int index)
    {                 
         T value = this[index];     
    }           
}
```

Admittedly I had to introduce the `index` parameter into `MyMethod`, but I'm assuming you were wanting to get the index from *somewhere*... if that's not what you meant, please clarify.

Answer (score 3):

This works fine for me:

```
public class MyClass<T>
{
    List<T> _items = new List<T>();

    public T this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            return _items[index];
        }
    }

    public void MyMethod()
    {
        T value = this[2];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Calling the indexer is fine, but it doesn't know which index you want.  If you make index a parameter of MyMethod it will work fine.

If you're trying to get the current index or something then you need to store a private variable, wire it up in your indexer and access that.

Your edited code compiles fine...

```
public class MyClass<T>
{
        public T this[int index]
        {
            get
            {
                ...
            }
            set
            {
                ...
            }
        }

        public void MyMethod()
        {   
             int middleIndex = ...;              
             T value = this[middleIndex ];     
             ...             
        }           
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you're not passing in a value for the index into the method `MyMethod` - can you post a little more code?  It looks like something is missing...

Answer (score 0):

Your offending code is here:

```
public void MyMethod<T>()
```

Your class `MyClass<T>` already has a generic type parameter T, so the generic `<T>` on `MyMethod` is unnecessary

Comment: It is offending because you're declaring a new T, and it has no relation to the outer T.